# How to pass an array as path parameter and fetch the response on the basis of each array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array of person type which I need to pass to an endpoint as path param and on the basis of type of person i need to fetch the corresponding personId.

This is my api

```
api.post("/users/:person_type"), (req, res) => {
let person_type = req.params;
db.query(
`SELECT person_id from persons where person_type = '${person_type}'`,
(err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(response.rows);
    res.json({ "PersonIdFetched": response.rows });
  }
    }
   );
  };
```

and here is my api integration

```
    let person = ["p1", "p2" ,"p3", "p4"];
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${person}`)
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.PersonIdFetched);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: you're using `post` so send the array in the body.

Comment: @marzelin Okay I will send the array in body but will the query execute for each value of array?

Comment: you need to modify server code to either get all of them in one query or to loop over the array and query one by one and then return all results.

Comment: Is it possible to apply loop for query in backend?